# How tall is Krang's robot body?

Tags: teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles, teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles-1987

1980's cartoon version. That is all.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approximately >7' tall.

[Shredder is 6'](http://tmnt2012series.wikia.com/wiki/Shredder)

[The average human body is 7.5 heads tall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_proportions), making Shredder's head 9.6" tall.  Assuming that Shredder and Kraang are standing the same distance away from the viewer, Kraang apears to be ~1.5 Shredder heads taller than Shredder.  This would make Kraang 86.4" tall, or about 7'3".

Edit:  the website above changed the height to 6' even, so I adjusted accordingly.
[This site fans argue between 5'11" and 6'2"](http://forums.thetechnodrome.com/showthread.php?t=31549).
[And this site says 6' as well.](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/shredder/4005-42406/)
[But this site clames 6'2"](http://members.tripod.com/derekchan_88/cgi-bin/profiles.htm).
[And this site claims 5'10".](http://www.writeups.org/shredder-teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles/)

So the consensus seems to be ~6' making Kraang over 7' in that picture.

Comment: There appears to be no evidence given in the wiki article ton substantiate Shredder's  height.

Comment: But can't crang change his body size at will? Iirc there's a scene he becomes giant

Comment: I never thought Shredder was 6’8”. The link doesn’t seem to be referencing the 1987 version. And of course I’m speaking about the robot body’s default height.

Comment: 7'3" sounds reasonable. Or the same height as Knicks center Kristaps Porzingis. I bet that Porzingis is better at hoops, though.

Comment: What? No. You can't use an artistic standard of height (7.5 heads) and apply it arbitrarily to another piece of art or even real life using that scale. You find a full body image of Shredder and find out how many heads he is in that style, with his own head, and derive your measurements from there.

Comment: More importantly, you can't use a height of a character from a completely different continuity *and* mutation as a reference to calculate the height. And then there's the issue that the supposed height is completely unsourced.

Comment: Krang is a Kraang.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the [***Size Transformation Actuator***](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles-1987&episode=s06e02) is set to. In season 6 episode 2, [*Krangenstein Lives*](https://turtlepedia.fandom.com/wiki/Krangenstein_Lives), after repairing [the *Molecular Amplification Unit* broken in season 1 episode 5](https://turtlepedia.fandom.com/wiki/Shredder_%26_Splintered):

> The body's size keeps fluctuating between enormous and tiny during the fight that ensues.

In this episode Krang's ecto-frame varies in size from towering over buildings to fitting in a Turtle's fist:

[image: Large]

[image: Small]

Its default size (season 2 episode 9) appears to be about 5 times [1987 Krang's height of 0.45 meter](https://turtlepedia.fandom.com/wiki/Shredder_%26_Splintered): 2.25 m or 7.38 ft (7'5") plus 10 cm (4") antenna, totaling **2.35 m or 7'9"**.

[image]

Comment: 7'9" would make Shredder 6'2" according to [this photo of Sun Ming and Xu Yan posing with their Guinness World Record certificate](https://www.mirror.co.uk/news/weird-news/meet-worlds-tallest-couple-combined-6423195).